# How do I make table rows the same height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a contact merge sort of page, and therefore need two tables side by side where you can select which data you want from each contact, but I need the rows to line up so it's easy for the user to select appropriate data. I'm using boostrap

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <form method="post" class="form-inline">
        <?php foreach($contacts as $contact): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-container">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Contact <?php echo $counter == 1 ? '1':'2'; ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Main Type:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $main_type_array[$contact->contact_main_type]; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="main_type"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Title:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_title; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="title"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">First Name:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_fname; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="first_name"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Last Name:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_sname; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="last_name"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Salutation:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_salu; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="salu"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Position:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_position; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="position"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Email Address:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_email; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="email"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Alt. Email:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_alt_email; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="alt_email"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Phone Number:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_phone; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="phone"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Mobile Number:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_mobile; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="mobile"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">PA Name:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_pa_name; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="pa_name"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">PA Email:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_pa_email; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="pa_email"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Type:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->old_type_new; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="old_type_new"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Interest Area 1:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_interest_area; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="ia1"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Interest Area 2:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_interest_area2; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="ia2"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Affilliation:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_affiliation; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="affiliation"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Source:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_source; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="source"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Location:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data"><?php echo $contact->contact_location; ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><input value="1" type="radio" name="location"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <td class="td_attr">Forum Interests:</td>
                                <td class="text-center td_data">
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($contact->forum_interests as $forum) {
                                        echo "$forum->forum_1word <br/>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center vert-align"><input value="1" type="radio" name="forum_interests"></td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php $counter++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Events</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Event Date</th>
                        <th>Event Title</th>
                        <th>Invite Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($events[$i] as $event): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $event->event_date ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $event->event_title; ?></td>
                            <Td><?php echo $contacts[$i]->invites[$event->event_id]; ?></Td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a 
div class="row" 
to wrap your for loop?

Comment: Where would I apply the row? I've tried putting the `<tr>` inside a `<div class="row">` but that just moves the table like halfway down the screen.

Comment: @A.Appleby
Sorry, i don't quite understand which table you're trying to adjust. 
But are you trying to put your contact table side by side?

If so, you might try removing "form-inline" from your form tag
if u want the inline, put it in your div class
`<form method="post" class="">
        <?php foreach($contacts as $contact): ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-inline">`

Comment: This didn't work either. All I want is two tables side by side which details for contact 1 on the left hand side, and details for the second contact on the right